# C# having a list what's the best way to print a board

Tags: c#, matrix

Having a list of 25 integers. What'd be the better approach to make a 5x5 board?

```
List<int> x = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 25).ToList();
```

Here's a list that's filled with 0. In the image below I had represented this list was `B(a)`.

I did this image to show you what's the problem I'm facing to. Notice that for example `B(b)[6]` has a value of `7`.

In a classic Matrix 5x5 the value of 6 would be 19. I'm not pretty sure how to face this problem, I think that for the game it'd better be treated like a list but with the purpose of showing the board it's a must to be like that.

[image]

How could I print this kind of board?

Comment: Are you looking for a two-dimensional array? `int[,] board = new int[5,5]`

Comment: "In a classic Matrix 5x5 the value of 6 would be 19. " why exactly?  So your problem is actually the different indexing? you want to keep the list but show a matrix, that I understood, but how exactly would you like to have the indexing done? you have a use case?

Comment: Yup, let's say that some of those indexes have some different value to 0, for example, let's say that the cell 19 has a value of 6. So I had to change the value (if I'm using a two-dimensional array) `board[1,0] = 6`. The thing is that I find easier to do`board[19-1] = 6`. So if I have a lot of values to change, I can do something like `board[i - 1] = value` I think I'm overthinking the problem tho.

Comment: I don't know how your game works, but in a 2 D array it would be easier to find adjacent fields. It is more complicated in a list of values. Ok apparently you have to print the matrix upside down. classic matrix means to you that you start counting in the left upper corner?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's what I meant with classic matrix, notice that the green area in the picture is showing the matrix starting from the lower left corner to the right, then right to the left, left to right and so on. The game is Snakes and Ladders so I don't think I need to find adjacent fields but sum or subtract the position where I am according to the snake/ladder. Let's say that for example the index 2 isn't a empty cell but a ladder, so instead of a 0 it has a 8 witch it means that I move 8 squares, so 2+8 = 10, I'd be in the n10 square.

Comment: How you represent the board internally and draw it on-screen are two completely different things.  It sounds like it makes sense to leave it as a straight list for the internal representation so you can jump ahead by x spots and get the next value. You're asking how to print it, but you haven't specified WHAT KIND OF APP you're working with. What is your output? Are you working with a Console App, WinForms, WebForms, WPF, something else?...

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the first step would be to convert the array to some representation of 2D data in some way, and then have a print method using the 2D data as input. One way to do this would be to create a wrapper around the array with methods suitable to indexing into the 1D array. For example:

```
public class My2DArray<T>
        public int Width { get; }
        public int Height { get; }
        public T[] Data { get; }
        public My2DArray(int width, T[] data)
        {
            Width = width; 
            Height = data.Length / width; // might want to check there is no remainder here
            Data = data;
        }
        public T this[int x, int y]
        {
            get => Data[y * Width + x];
            set => Data[y * Width + x] = value;
        }
        public string ToString(string valueSeparator , string rowSeparator)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                var row = y * Width;
                for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
                {
                    sb.Append(Data[row + x])
                        .Append(valueSeparator);
                }

                sb.Append(rowSeparator);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
}
```